# Create Dataframe column that uses a dictionary to map the corresponding key,value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to create a dataframe column that will take data from a dictionary and search DF for the value. Example below:

DF1:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
Dog      4.5     1.3     6.4
Cat      154      89      2
Frog     8        x       9
```

Dictionary = {'Dog':'ColC', 'Cat':'ColB', 'Frog':'ColD'}

Desired Dataframe: 'NewCol' column uses the dictionary to find the proper value

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    NewCol
Dog      4.5     1.3     6.4      1.3
Cat      154      89      2       154 
Frog     8        x       9        9
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lookup:

```
df['new_col'] = df.set_index('ColA').lookup(Dictionary.keys(), Dictionary.values())
```

Output:

```
   ColA   ColB ColC  ColD new_col
0   Dog    4.5  1.3   6.4     1.3
1   Cat  154.0   89   2.0     154
2  Frog    8.0    x   9.0       9
```